# Splitting a live trace into 6 parts?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, laser-cutting, live-trace

I am doing a project in my woodwork class and I need to split a design (in Illustrator) into multiple parts so that it can fit into the laser cutter.

This is the design i used:

[image: Original Design]

Next I simply put it into Illustrator and deleted the pieces on it (after a live trace) and ended up with this:

[image: Using Live Trace]

Now I have finalized that, I need to split it into 6 equal parts (you can see based on the lines where one would split it into 6 equilateral parts) but i have no clue where to start...

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: i just fiddled with this, and it might not be exactly what you want. These two models **will** work, though I am sure there are better ways of doing it.*

> Here is some of the problems: if you need the checkerboard pattern to
>   be exactly as above (i.e. defined difference between black and white)
>   you cannot divide the shape into six. You must divide it into three.
>
> If you need black-white checkerboard, keep 1/3, not 1/6, as going with 1/6 will give you this:

[image]

**1. suggestion**

`Trace` your image (fiddle with the setting until you find the best solution):
[image]

then go `expand` and `ungroup`. Then delete the parts you do not need:

[image]

**2. suggestion**

Create two hexagons. Overlap them:

[image]

Delete all the lines that does not describe a diamond. This is "rotateable" by 120 degrees and will then describe a hexagon.

[image]

Then you could either redraw the checkerboard parts, or use this shape as a clipping mask over your existing jpg:

[image]

That would probably give you a more accurate version than suggestion #1.

[image]